# Socket programming: Using fixed IP to bind server and configurable at client side

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I need to use my existing client server code:

1. The first set of code, I have works well on one machine with server binding to `127.255.255.255:9093` and client `127.0.0.1:9093`.
2. To make this work on different machines on same network, I used the IP_TRANSPARENT socket option of AF_NET and used `0.0.0.0:9093` at the server and `server_ip:9093` at client.

Now I need it to run on both local and different machines. I cannot change the IP that the server is binding to, it must be fixed, anything, but fixed.
I can change the IP that the client is binding to using config file.

What IPs should I use so that the program works on both same and different machines?

Note: Just if needed: Server code is in Java and client code is in C.

Comment: Removed bizarrre formatting. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Use 0.0.0.0. It means '*any* interface'. That's why it maps to INADDR_ANY.